# First time Magenta generated midi doesn’t play

Tags: tensorflow, midi, magenta

Trying to get first time Magenta installation to generate a playable midi.

After upgrading bazel on OSX to ‘Build label: 0.2.3’ Magenta 
works with this ‘example.mid’ input midi placed in a subdirectory.

tmp3/example.mid

> 4d54 6864 0000 0006 0001 0002 00dc 4d54
>  726b 0000 0019 00ff 5804
>   0402 1808 00ff
>  5103 03d0 9000 ff59 0200 0001 ff2f 004d
>  5472
>   6b00 0000 4000 c000 0090 3c64 8151
>  3c00 0b3e 6481 513e 000b 4064
>   8151 4000
>  0b41 6481 5141 000b 4364 8151 4300 0b45
>  6481 5145
>   000b 4764 8151 4700 0b48 6481
>  5148 0001 ff2f 00

after running

```
bazel build magenta:convert_midi_dir_to_note_sequences
```

then

```
mkdir out3
touch out3/newexample.mid

./bazel-bin/magenta/convert_midi_dir_to_note_sequences \
--midi_dir=/Users/user/Downloads/magenta-master/tmp3 \
--output_file=/Users/user/Downloads/magenta-master/out3/newexample.mid \
--recursive
```

you get

out3/newexample.mid

> 2101 0000 0000 0000 072b 7cb0 0a36 2f69
>  642f 6d69 6469 2f74 6d70
>   332f 3364 3864
>  3537 3835 6634 3838 6666 6438 3837 3566
>  3130
>   6131 3238 3538 6336 6636 6332 3135
>  3230 3638 120b 6578 616d 706c
>   652e 6d69
>  641a 0474 6d70 3320 dc01 2a04 1004 1804
>  3200 3a09
>   1100 0000 0000 006e 4042 0d08
>  3c10 6421 6666 6666 6666 ce3f 4216
>   083e
>  1064 1900 0000 0000 00d0 3f21 3333 3333
>  3333 df3f 4216
>   0840 1064 1900 0000 0000
>  00e0 3f21 9999 9999 9999 e73f 4216
>   0841
>  1064 1900 0000 0000 00e8 3f21 9999 9999
>  9999 ef3f 4216
>   0843 1064 1900 0000 0000
>  00f0 3f21 cdcc cccc cccc f33f 4216
>   0845
>  1064 1900 0000 0000 00f4 3f21 cccc cccc
>  cccc f73f 4216
>   0847 1064 1900 0000 0000
>  00f8 3f21 cccc cccc cccc fb3f 4216
>   0848
>  1064 1900 0000 0000 00fc 3f21 cccc cccc
>  cccc ff3f 49cc
>   cccc cccc ccff 3f13 5fbf
>  34

but the music file doesn’t play. Even if you add ‘ff2f 00’ (common suggestion) to the end.

How can you make this resulting file play in a player such as Quicktime 7? Any ideas?

Comment: The output is not a MIDI file. And the input already is a playable MIDI file.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand the generated output is a TFRecord file with NoteSequence protobufs abstraction not a midi. So, must be converted back into it’s original format before playable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've recently added a model that you can train to generate new sequences. Have a look at https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/blob/master/magenta/models/basic_rnn/README.md.

Thanks!